# Modx give to a user permissions to add new users

Tags: modx

I am using Modx, and I try to give to a user permission to add/edit/delete new users.. So far so good, the user can do that, the thing is that I get an annoying error message. (even everything works).
The message appears when I access the user info.

> Code: 200 OK {"success":false,"message":"Permission
>   denied!","total":0,"data":[],"object":[]}

Action for requests where I have this error:

> action: workspace/namespace/getlist
>
> action: security/user/setting/getList

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have some other permission. Shortly here is how you should get some hint what permission: when user edition is in progress please open browser console and check all AJAX calls via Network tab...one should return JSON from above. If so please check what MODX processor was requested in **action** form parameter.. f.e. it can be */users/getlist*.. so you should update your ACLs and add the permissions for the user list.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 requests for /getlist where I get this message, still I am not sure what more permissions to give him. Already have the most of "user" permissions set up.

Comment: This may be not only user permissions (_user/getlist_ was only as example)..please find what XHR request leads to an error (where you receive `Code: 200 OK {"success":false,"message":"Permission denied!` from server), I bet you have it there! And let me know what **action** param value passed. This will be your answer.

Comment: I updated the post, with the actions, also I tried to activate/ deactivate several permissions,but still the same result..